# 3d studio tag cleanup

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

[3d-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/3d-studio) should merge into [3ds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/3ds).

Comment: 3ds has 80 questions while 3d-studio only 9, are you sure that is the correct direction?

Comment: And Wikipedia says: *Autodesk 3ds Max, formerly 3D Studio Max* that doesn't feel right to rename it... but I'm not a user of those tags...

Comment: Fair enough, I'll swap it around.